# Cant access Internet through wired connection

Tags: internet

I downloaded and installed Ubuntu using the Windows installer. Everything is running smoothly. When I plug in my ethernet cable is recognizes that it is plugged in and says that I am connected. Whenever I try to access Firefox it says Firefox cannot locate the server. Any suggestions? I am very new to Linux as well as using cmd prompts for the terminal.

Comment: Are you connected to the internet via a proxy?

Comment: please open terminal and type: `ping google.com` after 5 retry press ctrl+c to stop it the see you have access to internet or not. if you are connected to internet, you will see this report at the end of ping log: `3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1999ms`

Comment: If you hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> from your desktop, it should open up a terminal window. From the terminal, what do you see if you type `ifconfig` and hit enter? It might be a lot of information, so you can also add a `|less` making the command `ifconfig | less` or `> filename.txt` making the command `ifconfig > filename.txt`and read the results in a text file by typing `nano filename.txt` or `gedit filename.txt`. Do you see a line that says `inet addr:` and your IP address?

Comment: No I am not connected via proxy

Comment: I retried 5 times and still could not connect

Comment: Is there a way I can screenshot? It show s a lot of information and which inet addr are we talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Lets see if its a DNS issue.

Type **Network** in your search and then open **Network Connections**. Under **Wired** you should see a connection named **Auto eth0** as seen below.

[image: Network Connections]

Click **Edit** from the right and enter your password and you should see a window similar to the one below.

[image: Connection Info]

Now change the method to **Automatic (DHCP) addresses only** and down the bottom next to DNS servers enter **8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4** as seen below. These are DNS servers provided by Google and are very reliable.

[image: DNS Settings]

Now click **Save** down the bottom and lastly lets restart your network connections to make sure we are using the new settings. The easiest way is to turn your network off and on again as seen in the image below. But if you are comfortable with the terminal type Terminal in your search and open it up then type the following to restart your network connections.

```
$sudo service networking restart
```

[image: Network Reset]

Now lets check before trying the internet again so type **Network** in your search again and this time choose **Network** and you should see something similar to the image below.

[image: Check Settings]

Now try your browser again and let me know how you go.

Answer (score 0):

- Check what's in /etc/resolv.conf ( if you can paste the output that will help).
- Also do 'route -n' and paste the output.

The reason why its not working could be the following.
- Gateway is not reachable ( or there is a alternate gateway configured which is also not reachable )
- DNS server is not reachable